PHP : Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in
I'm trying to submit a form details and gather all entered text field data and concatenate with url and pass to qrcode generator to show QrCode in pdf page with the entered data using fpdf library. After scanning that QrCode to show entered form data.
Here I'm facing an issue in concatenate url with string data.
  <php
.....
$str_det=$School_Name . "-" . $School_Place . "-" . $Student_Name;
$url="http://localhost/SCHL/qr_generator.php?code=";
$pdf->Image("http://localhost/SCHL/qr_generator.php?code=".$str_det, 100,100, 60, 60, "png");
....
?>

qr_generator.php:
<?php
  require_once("phpqrcode/qrlib.php");
  QRcode::png($_GET['code']);
?>

Error:

Warning: fopen(http://localhost/SCHL/qr_generator.php?code=Our Angels Mat Hr school-Valasaravakkam-Mahesh Sugumar): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in C:\xampp\htdocs\SCHL\fpdf.php on line 1274

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Can't open image file: http://localhost/SCHL/qr_generator.php?code=Our Angels Mat Hr school-Valasaravakkam-Mahesh Sugumar in C:\xampp\htdocs\SCHL\fpdf.php:267 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SCHL\fpdf.php(1276): FPDF->Error('Can't open imag...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\SCHL\fpdf.php(890): FPDF->_parsepng('http://localhos...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\SCHL\generate_pdf.php(56): FPDF->Image('http://localhos...', 100, 100, 60, 60, 'png') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SCHL\fpdf.php on line 267

http://localhost/SCHL/qr_generator.php does this link work when you test it outside the program

yes. its working without cancatenate... i just pass a charater 'a'..                                                                        $pdf->Image("http://localhost/SCHL/qr_generator.php?code=a", 100,100, 60, 60, "png");
$pdf->Output();                                                                                                                                                       https://ibb.co/xjMK8QR

are you able to generate the qrCode with the form field data without the pdf part

ok so if it works like this  $pdf->Image("localhost/SCHL/qr_generator.php?code=a", 100,100, 60, 60, "png"); $pdf->Output();  then try to make sure that there are no spaces in your concatenated data. Or try with one name

Its working but shows only qr code image. i just want to display in pdf...  $str_det=$School_Name . "-" . $School_Place . "-" . $Student_Name;
QRcode::png($str_det);
$pdf->Output();

I think the easy  solution will be to use a templating language like Twig to make a template then pass your data and your qrcode image then convert that to pdf or use Html2Pdf its very easy https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/tree/master/examples

Hi.. As you said i tried to remove the space and run .. still getting bad request error. i have posted a image link https://ibb.co/xjMK8QR . like that i have to show the template... form data with below qr code in pdf page.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

hi sir. i have done by concatenate the strings first and pass it in QRcode::png("concatenated string","file path");.. then passed the image file path in $pdf->Image('\file1.png',..);... Thank you for sharing information....
